# Typescript can class methods allow method chaining without returning 'this'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, method-chaining

I have made a **Mycalculator** class that implements the following **Calculator Interface** to be method chaining.

```
interface Calculator {
  add(a: number): void
  sub(a: number): void
  div(a: number): void
  mul(a: number): void
  display(decimalToDisplay: number): void
  allClear(): void
  reset(value: number): void
}


class MyCalculator implements Calculator {
  private _current: number;

  constructor(public value: number) {
    this._current = value
  }

  add(a: number): MyCalculator {
    this.current += a
    return this
  }
  sub(a: number): MyCalculator {
    this.current -= a
    return this
  }
  div(a: number): MyCalculator {
    this.current /= a
    return this
  }
  mul(a: number): MyCalculator {
    this.current *= a
    return this
  }

  get current (): number {
    return this._current
  }

  set current (result: number)  {
    this._current = result
  }

  reset (value: number) {
    this.current = value
    return this
  }

  display(decimalToDisplay: number = 2): MyCalculator {
    console.log(this.current.toFixed(decimalToDisplay))
    return this
  }

  allClear(): MyCalculator {
    this.current = 0
    return this
  }

}

// Test
new MyCalculator(3).add(5).mul(5).div(3).div(3).display() // 4.44
new MyCalculator(5).add(5).mul(5).div(5).display().allClear().reset(5).add(5).display() // 10.00, 10.00
```

In the above code, I have some questions

- Can each method allow method chaining without `return this`?
- If not, Could you tell me what is the correct way to chaning methods?
- If not, How do I declare the add, sub, div, and mul methods in the interface to return Mycalculator types?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use "this" in interface as  return type.

Comment: Instead of `return this`, you can also `return` a new instance.

Comment: @Vayrax It works! Thank you

Comment: You might consider making your methods and the _current variable `static`. That way, you don't have to make a `new MyCalculator()` instance to call the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this right. Returning this is the normal way to implement method chaining. But there are some problems. The methods should the interfaces type.

```
interface Calculator {
  add(a: number): Calculator
  sub(a: number): Calculator
  div(a: number): Calculator
  mul(a: number): Calculator
  display(decimalToDisplay: number): void
  allClear(): void
  reset(value: number): void
}
```

Even in you implementation of this interface, the resulting type is Calculator. What you want is called polymorphism. The caller of the method just wants some Calculator as result and it is not important what kind of implementation he gets. So one example for such a method would look like that:

```
class MyCalculator implements Calculator {
// ...
  add(a: number): Calculator {
    this.current += a
    return this
  }
// ....
}
```

But mind that your calculator doesn't work correct. 1 + 2 * 3 is the same as 1 + (2 * 3) but your calculator would treat that as (1 + 2) * 3. Maybe you don't want this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my question even I didn't ask. And I need to modify it so that it can be computed in the usual arithmetic order.